# How can i listening or monitoring pending Smart Contract function or events?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development, ethers.js

Hello everybody hope all are good ? i need your help ..

Note i already know how we can monitoring **mempool** but i'm talking about **function of smart contract**...

As **mempool** with **pending** Tx, i want make the same but get **pending** function call from smart contract.

If i call function 'swap' or 'transfer' from **smart contract** how can i monitoring it ?

Sincerely Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
const AddressOfToken = '0x123aBc';
const AddressOfToken_ABI = require('./"yourABIname".json')   
//File in same folder with ABI of CONTRACT

const Contract = new ethers.Contract(AddressOfToken ,AddressOfToken_ABI , 
provider);  
//Need add an endpoint to provider (ETH, BSC ...)


Contract.on("Transfer",async (from, to, value, event, ) => {

const info = {
from: from,
to: to,
value: ethers.utils.formatUnits(value, "DecimalfromContractHere"),
event: event,
hash : event.transactionHash,
: event.args[1],
};
})
```

**This return pending Tx function from contract**

Sincerely